# Могу ли я использовать Wordpress плагины в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу  использовать плагин для бронирования времени у врача,

1. Могу ли я использовать плагины  Wordpress в Laravel ?
2. Можно ли использовать  функционально написанные плагины в Laravel ?

Нашел много **систем** платных и бесплатных которые очень большие, но легко интегрируются с Wordpress.

3. Можно ли использовать большие системы с Laravel ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Wordpress` и `Laravel` это 2 разные вещи. Плагины не подойдут, т.к. они заточены под "ядро" вордпресса. У `Laravel` свое ядро, архитектура и прочее.

По поводу второго пункта, все зависит от того, на сколько плагин зависит от вп, возможно можно будет его переписать.

По поводу третьего, вернуть к первому: `WordPress != Laravel` две абсолютно разные вещи, вп заточен под плагины и их разработку, `laravel` под собственный колхоз и компосер (возможно кстати там уже есть решения которые вам нужны).